# Ansible loop over multiple dictionaries/lists

Tags: list, loops, dictionary, ansible

In my playbook, I'd like to loop over two dictionaries (or one dictionary and one list). One is a list (or dictionary) of Domains, the other one is a dictionary that includes the aws-regions with the corresponding server-IPs to use for the DNS-Entries for latency based routing. I want to set for each domain one DNS-record for each aws-region.

```
- name: set DNS records for Domains
  route53:
    zone: "{{ item[0].key }}"
    record: "{{ item[0].key }}"
    value: "{{ item[1].value.server_ip }}"
    region: "{{ item[1].key }}"
    identifier: "{{ item[1].key }}"
  with_nested:
  - "{{ domain_dict }}"
  - "{{ aws_dict }}"
```

With two lists, the example works fine. How do I get it to work using at least one dictionary?

domain_dict: (could be a list as well)

```
domain_dict:
  mytest1.example:
  mytest2.example:
  mytest3.example:
```

aws_dict:

```
aws_dict:
  us-east-1:
   # some other region-related stuff like ami-id,...
    server_ip: 1.2.3.4
  us-west-1:
   # some other region-related stuff
    server_ip: 1.2.3.5    
  us-west-2:
   # some other region-related stuff
    server_ip: 1.2.3.6
  #all other aws-regions
```

Comment: Could you include the content of your variables: `domain_dict` and `aws_dict` please?

Answer (score 1):

A custom `lookup_plugin` is your best bet. Otherwise it'll be an ugly sequence of `set_fact`.

PS:
While you ordinarily shouldn’t have to, should you wish to write your own ways to loop over arbitrary datastructures, you can read [Developing Plugins](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html) for some starter information. Each of the above features are implemented as plugins in ansible, so there are many implementations to reference